# Import to Access a TXT database, that each record has multiple lines?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm having trouble importing to Access a TXT file that is formatted in a way similar to this:

```
Johnny Doe Nobody        018918651Something else about this guy       556161  001
159159189489405604640       3rd Avenue - Random Street 123 - Alaska
Mary Rose                468486464Something else about this gal       564566  002
194984498446415615648       3rd Avenue - Random Street 456 - Alaska
Johnny Doe Jr.           265262655Something about this dude           556558  003
489446811897188678678       3rd Avenue - Random Street 789 - Alaska
```

The problem: Each person has more than one line! How can I parse this file? Thanks!!

**-EDIT-**
Even worse, some databases can come like this:

```
Johnny Doe Nobody        018918651Something else about this guy       556161  001
159159189489405604640       3rd Avenue - Random Street 123 - Alaska
Johnny Doe Nobody        018918651Something else about this guy       556161  001
151515456489489494894       3rd Avenue - Random Street 123 - Alaska
Johnny Doe Nobody        018918651Something else about this guy       556161  001
165156161561561615165       3rd Avenue - Random Street 123 - Alaska
```

And I gotta make it just one record! :(

Comment: Can't use the import wizard. Use VBA to open text file object and read in each line and parse data elements into an array. Test each line for beginning character is alpha or numeric to determine if it is continuation of record. However, all those spaces will complicate. Are data elements separated by tabs or repeated spaces? Should there be separator between `018918651` and `Something`? Unless you want everything all in one long text field.

Comment: Actually, if there are always two lines for each record, don't even need to do the test for alpha/numeric. Unfortunately, separating name parts with any consistency will be virtually impossible. The address info could be broken up by secondary parsing on the hyphens.

Comment: On second thought, checking for alpha/numeric is easier approach.

Comment: Actually "018918651" and "Something" are an example of something that happens of the database... because each field is fixed by number of characters, (1-15 is always the name), sometimes there's fields that aren't separated...

Comment: And the problem is, some databases can have up to 6 lines for each person! See the EDIT for more info... And to make it a nightmare, my knowledge on SQL, doesn't go much beyond SELECT... Some guy long ago made a program that parsed this file, but was java, and I don't have it...

Comment: What do you mean by '1 record'? What is the 21-digit number for? They should be combined into 1 field? Code would have to store name into a variable and check it against name in each 'record' and if it changes then create new record in table and set variable to the new name. I'm sure it's all doable, the logic just gets more complicated. Write out the decision process you would follow (pseudocode), build a flow chart if it helps you, then build code to follow that logic.

Comment: By "1 record" I mean, one person on the database... But anyway, I'm not a programmer, so I think I can't accomplish that. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If the state is mandatory say in this case Alaska or any other state the '-' is mandatory then i would simply read it line by line and then add the immediate next line which contains the '-' and use that.

If the line does not include a hyphen('-') then its a new line.

It totally depends on what the structure of the base file format is.

Example.

Buffer string = Johnny Doe Nobody        018918651Something else about this guy       556161  001

Search hyphen if its there then add that to buffer and read next if it contains any hyphen. If it does not then its a new line. Process the buffered line and do the same again in loop.

Comment: How I would do it on Access?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code blatantly stolen from here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27402651/Remove-Every-Other-LineBreak-in-Text-File.html
This will remove every other CRLF found in the specified input file and writes the result out to the specified output file. Run this on your text file first and then import the output file as a text file with fixed length records.

```
Sub CleanFile()
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TriStateUseDefault = -2
Dim strInput As String
Dim strOutput As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objInput As Object
Dim objOutput As Object
Dim arrLines As Variant
Dim i As Integer

strInput = "C:\temp\in.txt"
strOutput = "C:\temp\out.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInput, ForReading, False, TriStateUseDefault)
arrLines = Split(objInput.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
objInput.Close

Set objOutput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutput, ForWriting, True)

For i = 0 To UBound(arrLines) Step 2
   If i + 1 > UBound(arrLines) Then
      objOutput.WriteLine arrLines(i)
   Else
      objOutput.WriteLine arrLines(i) & " " & arrLines(i + 1)
   End If
Next

objOutput.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! Now needs to deal with the duplicate names. Still don't know what poster wants to do with the 21-digit element.